# Why is a bridged TAP interface receiving a link local IP address?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, kvm, ipv6

I am using libvirt with qemu-kvm on Debian 10 and I have created a virtual machine with bridged network, and it has created a TAP interface named `vnet0` which has been added to my bridge. What I don't understand is why is this TAP interface receiving a link local IP address. In addition to figuring out *why* this is happening, I would like to know if this can present any problems.

```
7: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f2:30:e9:a0:ff:f1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.17/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic br0
    valid_lft 3551sec preferred_lft 3551sec
    inet6 fe80::f030:e9ff:fea0:fff1/64 scope link
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:61:37:9c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe61:379c/64 scope link
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 0):

All the interfaces have a link-local ipv6 address on Linux, unless you manually remove it, globally disable ipv6 or set the `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/<interface>/disable_ipv6` sysctl to 1.

Comment: If I disable ipv6 for the interface acting as the switch port, does that mean the device on the other end will be unable to use ipv6?